# Item title not displayed in portrait with SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-contextmenu

In my activity, I have an action mode with a single item which has a title and an icon.

I want both the title and the icon to be displayed, so I use SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT and SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS flags.

In landscape orientation, it's fine. I have title + icon.
But in portrait orientation only the icon is displayed (though there's a lot of free space). Does anyone know what I could do to fix it ?

Note that the title is correctly displayed if I remove the icon.

Here is my sample code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startActionMode(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.add("Item 1").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) { return false; }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) { }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) { return false; }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know what I could do to fix it ?

I doubt that you can. "Always" and "with text" are requests, not commands. The framework does not always honor either of them.

Comment: Is there anyway we can override this and make the text always visible along with the icon? It is not displaying the text even if I use only one menu in portrait and there is a lot of free space.

Comment: Try `MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT`. This got the settings item with icon and "SETTINGS" text to show my Nexus 7 in landscape mode.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I don't believe what you're saying is true. The documentation states: _The parameter actionEnum is a flag set. One of SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS, SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM, or SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER should be used, and you may optionally OR the value with SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT. SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT requests that when the item is shown as an action, it should be shown with a text label._

Comment: @prettyvoid: I am very confident that what I have here is true. If you define 100 `<item>` elements with `showAsAction` set to `always`, only a few will make it into the action bar as toolbar buttons, because there will not be room for them all. Similarly, `withText` is ignored if the action bar implementation feels there is insufficient room -- you can see that in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/ActionBarDemoNative). Finally, the passage you quoted agrees with me that `withText` "requests" something.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I stand corrected, I didn't give your reply much thought. So I'm guessing one would have to set his own 'custom' view to the actionbar, to get the desired behavior (text+icon always) to be consistent. Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: @prettyvoid: "So I'm guessing one would have to set his own 'custom' view to the actionbar, to get the desired behavior (text+icon always) to be consistent" -- yes. However, that may increase the odds that your item will fall into the overflow due to lack of available space, particularly on phones in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding this menu item via code try to use this attribute:

```
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

and add it to the item in the menu.xml

Comment: That's right. It should be equivalent; however it's a good practice to check alternatives when one solution doesn't work. What is the Project Build Target of your project? Do you use compatibility library for the actionBar?

Comment: No compatibility library. And I use android:minSdkVersion="14" so far