# action item is not displayed in the actionbar

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

No matter, what I do, text is not displayed in the action item along with the image. Can someone please help me with this. Have been struggling with this for few days.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


             SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Types");
                subMenu1.add("type-1");
                subMenu1.add("type-2");
                subMenu1.add("type-3");

                MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
                subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.down_arrow);
                subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);



        return true;
    }
```

In the above code "**Types**" text is not displayed along with the icon. Only icon is displayed. If I remove the `subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.down_arrow);` line, then the text is displayed. But I want both. Here I am adding sub menu items to the action item, so that I get dropdown.

As I didn't get the suggestions for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080269/setting-the-dropdown-for-the-action-bar-item), I decided to follow at least in this way of adding sub menu items. Here I have two questions.

`1)` How to make the text visible along with the icon.

`2)` How to listen to the submenuitems' clicks i.e., how do we know when sub items are clicked. When Item is clicked, we can listen in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item), but what is the case for submenu items?

If someone can help me on this, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unfortunately SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT is only a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13420797/1025599). From personal experience it seems to work in landscape mode though.
2. You can listen in onOptionsItemSelected() for submenu items as well

   > ```
   > subMenu1Item.add(GROUP_ID, ITEM_ID, ORDER, "type-1");
   >
   > // ...
   >
   > @Override
   > public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   >    switch (item.getItemId()) {
   >       case ITEM_ID: // do something
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

Comment: Yeah. I don't have issues in landscape mode. I have problem with portrait mode. Even in portrait mode, I am getting icon and later text. But I need text and later icon. Please suggest. What is the use of ActionProvider? Can it be implemented in actionbarsherlock too?

Comment: Yep, ActionBarSherlock has its own Action Provider classes, take a look at the [examples](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ActionProviders.java)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to change the submenu items'(in my case type-1, type-2 ...) background? As I have my screen as white, the submenu items having the background of white(by default) is barely visible. Because of the time factor I have decided to finish it with skipping icon.

Comment: You can change the background by setting a [theme in styles.xml](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please answer my second question?

Comment: Do you mean changing the order of text and icon for an action item? I don't think this is possible, sorry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21953/discussion-between-alex-ios-and-nachi)

Comment: No, I was talking about my question numbered as 2 in my question above.